# exponential time series for multiple time series data

Tags: r, time-series, smoothing, exponential, holtwinters

My data has different start and end points.

```
structure(list(item = c("Card", "Card", "Card", "Card", "Card", 
"Card", "Card", "Card", "battery", "battery", "battery", "battery", 
"battery", "laptop", "laptop", "laptop", "laptop", "laptop", 
"laptop", "laptop"), sales = c(20.4, 29, 26, 40, 35, 36, 28, 
41, 70, 75, 78, 99, 40, 100, 132, 123, 145, 125, 145, 124), Date = structure(c(17784, 
17791, 17798, 17805, 17812, 17819, 17826, 17833, 17608, 17615, 
17622, 17629, 17636, 17713, 17726, 17739, 17752, 17765, 17778, 
17791), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried doing

```
ts_test <- ts(multiple_ts, frequency=52)
```

to convert to time series but it failed

```
structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20.4, 29, 26, 40, 35, 36, 28, 41, 
70, 75, 78, 99, 40, 100, 132, 123, 145, 125, 145, 124, 17784, 
17791, 17798, 17805, 17812, 17819, 17826, 17833, 17608, 17615, 
17622, 17629, 17636, 17713, 17726, 17739, 17752, 17765, 17778, 
17791), .Dim = c(20L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("item", "sales", 
"Date")), .Tsp = c(1, 1.36538461538462, 52), class = c("mts", 
"ts", "matrix"))
```

Can some one help me how to convert to time series group by item and apply exponential smoothing to each item.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the data frame into a 3 column zoo object `z` and from `z` create a list of `ts` objects `L`.  Apply exponential smoothing to each component of `L` giving `HW`.  Then plot each of those.  Note that `ts` objects cannot represent `Date` class directly so we omit the X axis and draw it ourself in `pltHW`.

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(multiple_ts, index = "Date", split = "item")
L <- lapply(as.list(z), function(x) as.ts(na.omit(x)))
HW <- lapply(L, HoltWinters, beta = FALSE, gamma = FALSE)

# given HoltWinters object x get fitted values as zooreg object
fitHW <- function(x) {
  fitted <- fitted(x)
  zooreg(fitted[, 1], as.Date(start(fitted)), frequency = frequency(fit))
}

# plot
pltHW <- function(x, sub) {
  plot(x, sub = sub, xaxt = "n")
  fit <- fit(x)
  Axis(time(fit), side = 1)
  invisible(x)
}

par.old <- par(mfrow = c(3, 1))
junk <- Map(pltHW, HW, names(HW))
par(par.old)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I tried this way,but  for `junk <- Map(pltHW, HW, names(HW))` i got the following error ` Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large `.And is there any way to unlist and get in a ts model where we can see the fitted values and actual values in same frame@G. Grothendieck

Comment: Using the data in the question I can't reproduce that error. It gives the output shown for me.  Have factored out `fitHW` in the answer and so `do.call("merge", lapply(HW, fitHW))` gives the fitted values.

Comment: When I actually applied to my whole data set and `read.zoo(multiple_ts, index = "Date", split = "item")` ran this code.The error I get is `Error in merge.zoo` `series cannot be merged with non-unique index entries in a series`

Comment: You will need to provide reproducible code and data.

Comment: How do we unnest the data which doesn't have same lengths@G.Grothendieck

Comment: unnesting does not require equal size components. In fact `lengths(L)` is `c(5, 8, 7)`.